# Texture not showing up in Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing

So I have a texture assigned to the selected object and it is UV mapped to the texture but the mesh doesn't change its appearance. Anyone know what I can do?[image]

Comment: could you please share your file (at least this part)? make sure you've packed the image

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have forgotten to enable the "Use Nodes" option in the Shader Editor.

[image]